# How to Fill and Stroke the SVG rectangle with corners with negative radius?

Tags: svg

I need to create a block with specific borders around it:

[image: example of the borders]

I want to have this block scalable, that is why I try doing it with svg.

Here is what I've done:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none slice" viewBox="0 0 300 400">
  <path stroke-width="1" stroke="#7DD37D" fill="red" d="
    M20 0h260
    m20 20v360
    m-20 20H20
    m-20 -20V20
    M0 20a20 20 0 0 0 20 -20
    M300 20a20 20 0 0 1 -20 -20
    M300 380a20 20 0 0 0 -20 20
    M0 380a20 20 0 0 1 20 20" id="path"/>
</svg>
```

[Demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/SleepWalker/pen/OPNmMa)

The border was created as path from lines and arcs.
The problem is, that I can't make svg to fill the area inside this path. It fills some space inside arcs instead of rectangle. What I'm doing wrong?

When I do something similar with Inkscape, the resulting path is combined from lines and Cubic Bezier curves. Can it be done with simple arcs instead of Bezier curves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you use a move ('m' or 'M') path command, it creates a new subpath.  Each subpath gets filled, not the whole thing.

If you want the whole thing filled, it has to be a continuous path.  In other words, in this case, it should be a move followed by a line, then an arc, then another line, and arc, and so on until you have completed all four sides of the shape.